# Woocommerce Checkout Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, jscript

For some reason checkout page isnt loading jquery anymore and my checkout button isn't working.

I'm having this console issue in both lines.
Any ideas please? I'm new with jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".cart-main-buttons .update-cart-btn").click(function(ev){ 

  ev.preventDefault();
  $(".cart-buttons-hidden input[name='update_cart']").trigger('click');
});

$(".cart-main-buttons .checkout-button").click(function(ev){ 
   ev.preventDefault();
   $(".cart-buttons-hidden input[name='proceed']").trigger('click');
});
});
```

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var $txt = $("#coupon-code-form input[name='coupon_code']");
$("#coupon-code-form").submit(function(ev) {

   ev.preventDefault();
   if($txt.val().length) {
   $(".cart-form input[name='coupon_code']").val( $txt.val() );
   $(".cart-form input[name='apply_coupon']").click();

} else { $txt.focus(); }
});
});
```

Comment: Simply the jQuery framework has not been loaded. Check your `<head>`, jQuery should not appear. You have to load it. Please check out [this link](https://www.mojowill.com/developer/using-javascript-with-wordpress-correctly/)

Comment: Did you set up the checkout page in your woocommerce settings? This If you put a woocomerce checkout shortcode on some page, but don't link it to woocommerce settings you'll get the warning that the JavaScript isn't loaded on this page.

Comment: Pretty sure that WooCommerce enqueues jQuery. But a script error anywhere would break everything and unfortunately this falls under the "debug my code" section of things that are off-topic.